# Rename file to match containing folder's name

Tags: automator

I have a collection of image files grouped into folders named `Project_01`, `Project_02`, etc. Using Automator, I have composed a workflow that asks the user for a folder, and combines the images in that folder into a single PDF document. The *destination folder* for the output PDF file can be determined with a variable; however, the *file name* field of the action expects a constant string.

Is there any way, maybe through renaming, that I can Automator have the output file give the name of the containing folder, e.g. `Project_01.pdf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a variable with the name you want, the easiest way would be to add a **Rename Finder Items** action after the PDF is created. Set it to *Name Single Item*, and you can just drag in the variable as the new name.

[image: rename finder items]

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thank you! I didn't even know the *variables* view existed until now!